# Why Firefox font-family render is so horrible than Chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I'm checking my website right now with Firefox 5, and I see that the rendering of the fonts is terrible.

This is the difference between Firefox (5) and Chrome : just see for example the text `Jeffe` how is rendered...

[image]

The default font-family is :

```
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

Why this behaviour? And how can I fix this trouble?

My actual OS : Windows 7 Professional

Comment: @Barry Brown : update the question with the answer!

Comment: You should never rely on fonts rendering a specific way.  Of all things, font rendering is probably the most variable from platform to platform.

Comment: @thirtydot : uhm, so How can I fix this problem? Changing the whole font-family? I see that Arial or Verdana is better rendered. Anyway, I found very strange this, because many website use Times New Roman, but I didnt notice those differents :(

Comment: Try: Firefox > Options > Advanced > General and then uncheck *Use hardware acceleration when available*. Let me know if this did the trick.

Comment: @tw16 : no, that Trick doesnt have any effect.

Comment: @tw16: I think you can disable DirectWrite in Firefox, but that's not a solution. Every other user of Firefox will have it turned on.

Comment: @thirtydot: I know, but it was a way to see if that is what was causing the issue.

Comment: @markzzz: Did you restart Firefox after unchecking the box?

Comment: For what it's worth, I find the "Firefox" screenshot above easier to read (better letter spacing, less color banding).

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky : really? On Which OS? I find it so terrible :)

Comment: @markzzz I'm on Mac, but that shouldn't matter much; I'm looking at your screenshots, not your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using CSS Reset to reduce inconsistencies between different browsers.

Look up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset, or search online for `css reset`.

I can't guarantee that this will work, but it should help. You can even customize it to get what you want.

(IMO, it's not that horrible. I actually like the font better than chrome.)

## Note:

Brad said (in your comments) that you should not depend on rendering fonts in a specific way. I agree with this. In addition, some people may like the font the way it is. It is much better to leave it alone, rather than trying to control the font rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and see if it helps...

On Firefox 42, inside about:config, the **gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode** definitely changes the way the fonts are rendered on Windows OS. You can make the changes and see live what the differences are. **What you are going to want to do is actually search for this value and make sure it is the only one visible in your about:config window.** The reason for this is below.

---

#### The options are as follows:

> - **-1** (Firefox default) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527786)
> - **0** (default) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527788)
> - **1** (aliased) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527789)
> - **2** (GDI Classic) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527790)
> - **3** (GDI Natural) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527791)
> - **4** (Natural) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527792)
> - **5** (Natural Symmetric) [screenshot](https://bug652141.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=527793)

**A word of caution.** When making changes to this value on my system, choosing **1** completely removes all text rendered in the browser. This means all your tabs, interface, webpage and about:config text might become completely invisible. If this happens, don't freak out, just double click on the bar where the value should be and change it back to **0** or **-1**. This is why you want to do a search for the actual value first, so that there is only one entry visible and you can change it back if something goes wrong. Trust me, I learned the hard way.

Source: [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652141)